# User sized based array function to print out something if there are values higher than 90

Tags: c++, function, boolean

Im setting up a user size based array to enter a number of scores and print out the highest and lowest values and the average. I also want to use a boolen function to print out if there are any A grades or not (Scores higher than 90) However im not quite sure how to code it. I attempted below with the getAScores function but its not working.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
#include <iomanip>  
#include <cstdlib>

int compare(const void* pa, const void* pb) 
{ 
  const int& a = *static_cast<const int*>(pa); 
  const int& b = *static_cast<const int*>(pb); 
  if (a < b) return -1; // negative if a<b 
  if (a > b) return 1; // positive if a>b 
  return 0; // 0 for tie 
} // compare 

double getAverage(int* score, int n) 
{ 
  int sum = 0; 
  int i = 0; 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    sum += score[i]; 
  double average = double(sum) / n; 
  return average; 
} // getAverage 
//Boolen Function to see if there are A grades present 
bool getAGrades(int* score) 
{ 
  int i = 0;
  if (score[i] >= 90){
  return true;
  cout << "there is at least one A"<<endl;
  }else {
   return false;
  cout<<" No A Grades "<<endl;
}
}
int main() 
{  
  int size;
  cout << "How many scores? ";
  cin >> size;
  cin.ignore(1000, 10);
  int* score = new int[size];  

  int i; // loop counter 
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
  { 
    cout<< "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> score[i]; 
    cin.ignore(1000, 10); 
  } // for 

qsort(score, size, sizeof(int), compare); 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout << score[i] << ' ';
  }
  cout <<endl;
  cout << "Lowest score  = " << score[0] << endl;
  cout << "Highest score = " << score[size-1] << endl;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
  cout << "Average = " << getAverage(score, size) << endl; 
  //this is where i want it to print if there are a grades or not
  getAGrades(score);


  return 0; 
} // main
```

Comment: Please elborate what you want from this function: bool getAGrades(int* score). Currently it only looks at one index(0), which does not make sense.

Comment: In addition, try not to use cin.ignore(). I am assuming this is a basic homework where you wont need to carry out complex input filtering.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework-tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to look at all indexes (like you have done in `getAverage`). This requires that `getAGrades` knows the size of the array.

Also, note that it does not make sense to put a `cout` after a `return` - it will never get executed.